# How to enable browser tabs after using window.open to launch a new window

Tags: javascript

I've got a link which launches a new window using

```
window.open( url, '_blank', 'height=400,...')
```

The window opens fine but tabs are disabled.  Is there a way to launch a new window with tabs enabled?

I tried adding as many options as I could think of that might have an effect! ;-)

```
window.open( url, '_blank', 'height=400, resizable=yes,toolbar=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=yes,titlebar=yes');
```

Thanks
Clem

Comment: have you tried _self?

Comment: No but I don't want to replace the current page, I do want to launch a new window.  Thanks tho.

Answer (score 0):

just found out that, what you are willing to do. It's not supported to Chrome bowers, due to `security` and **memory** concerns.

You can find all this info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open#Toolbar_and_chrome_features).

> ```
> toolbar
> ```
>
> If this feature is on, then the new secondary window renders the Navigation Toolbar (Back, Forward, Reload, Stop buttons). In addition to the Navigation Toolbar, Mozilla-based browsers will render the **Tab Bar** if it is visible, present in the parent window. (If this feature is set to no all toolbars in the window will be invisible, for example extension toolbars).
>
> Supported in: Internet Explorer 5+, Netscape 6.x, Netscape 7.x, Mozilla 1.x, Firefox 1.x

Comment: Hi Alvaro, thanks for the link but I'm not seeing where it says that if you launch a new window, the tabs are disabled.

Comment: Ok, I guess my brain is not working correctly... I see it says "In addition to the Navigation Toolbar, Mozilla-based browsers will render the Tab Bar if it is visible, present in the parent window."  But they are present in the 'parent' window -- if that means the page from which I did the window.open.  I also tried this in IE and get the same result -- tabs are disabled after the window.open.  Clem

Comment: Basically, they disable it because of security and memory reasons, sorry about that. The links and the test prove the behavior.

Comment: @Clem if this answer helped you, you can mark as right